# rJava .jcall return type issue

Tags: rjava

I am facing an issue with returning any type of array with `.jcall()`. Here is my code.

```
public class Test(){
  public static double[] sample(){

  double[] nobjarr = new double[5]
  nobjarr[0] = 1.0;
  nobjarr[1] = 1.0;
  nobjarr[2] = 1.0;
  nobjarr[3] = 1.0;
  nobjarr[4] = 1.0;

  return nobjarr;
}

}
```

In R, I am calling using .jcall

```
library(rJava)                          
.jinit()   
.jaddClassPath("path to .class file")    
objT <- .jnew("Test")    
res  <- .jcall(objT,"[D","sample")
```

For this I get an error saying "Error in .jcall(objT, "[D", "sample") :method sample with signature ()[D not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
Test <- J( "Test" )
Test$sample()
```

This uses the reflection based API that is in `rJava` for several years now and is much more convenient than the low level `.jnew, .jcall` interface.

Comment: @pommedeterresautee have you measured it ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know rJava, but it looks like you were telling the library to look for an instance method when the method is actually static.  Check the documentation to see what the first argument to jcall should be for a static method.