# package rjava jcall error in R

Tags: java, r, rjava

I want to use R to input a parameter into Java, for example "1000". Then method of StringToNum process and output its return to R,namely 1000. Seems it is the work of .jcall(), but I dont know how to do with its parameters.As I dont know Java, Could you please help me? 
Thank you very much!

Java code

```
package com.mingdong.rcalljava.test;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class StringToNum
{
 private String inputString = null;

 public StringToNum(String inputString)
{
  this.inputString = inputString;
}

 public StringToNum()
{
}

 public int convertStringToInt() 
{
    if (this.inputString == null) {
    this.inputString = "100";
    }
    return Integer.valueOf(this.inputString).intValue();
}

 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   StringToNum stringToNum = new StringToNum();
   int num = stringToNum.convertStringToInt();
   System.out.println("num:" + num);
  }
 }
```

R code

```
library(rJava)
.jinit()
.jinit('D:/Eclipse/dailyjob/javaProject/TestRCallJava.jar')

## .jaddClassPath("D:\\Eclipse\\dailyjob\\javaProject\\TestRCallJava.jar")

inputString <- .jnew("java.lang.String","1000")
inputString %instanceof% "java.lang.String"

StringToNum <- .jnew("com.mingdong.rcalljava.test.StringToNum")
StringToNum %instanceof% "com.mingdong.rcalljava.test.StringToNum"

.jcall(StringToNum,returnSig= "V", "main",inputString )
Error in .jcall(StringToNum, returnSig = "V", "main") : 
method main with signature ()V not found
```

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656732/rjava-jcall-return-type-issue/18656827#18656827 I think the problem is, that `main` is a static method which should not be called on the object reference but the class itself. See also the rJava documentation for `J`.

Comment: Thank you Beasterfield! Appreciate for your help!

Comment: Still confused.So what should I do? change a function or just change the parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues. On the Java side in `main` you call the constructor `new StringToNum()` which does not exist. The main method should rather look like:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  StringToNum stringToNum = new StringToNum( args[0] );
  int num = stringToNum.convertStringToInt();
  System.out.println("num:" + num);
}
```

Maybe this solves already your problem. However, in general you call static methods in Java not on the object but on the class. If you'd call the `main` method from Java you'd have to call

```
StringToNum.main( "1000" );
```

instead of calling

```
StringToNum obj = new StringToNum( "" );
obj.main( "1000" );
```

You should also avoid to call the low-level functions (indicated by starting with a `.`) of the rJava package.  So as indicated in [rJava .jcall return type issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656732/rjava-jcall-return-type-issue/18656827#18656827) the proper call would be

```
J("com.mingdong.rcalljava.test.StringToNum")$main( "1000" ) # untested
```